# Android - Swipe to refresh Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, refresh, swipe, reload

I have an android app with a Fragment that downloads data from a web service and place it in a list of textViews (I am not using a ListView). Is there a way to reload the fragment every time the user pull the screen? (swipe to refresh)

Comment: So, did you found a solution to the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener`

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(yourfragment.this);


@Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // Refreshing your data by calling web service again (remove old data)
    }
```

Comment: **YourFragment.class** `@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(yourfragment.this);` **AFTER ONCREATE** `private void yourDataParser(){//stuff}` **Finally your onRefresh** `public void onRefresh(){yourDataParser();}` **HINT** Don't call your refresh before yourDataParser(), this tooked me 34 Minutes -.-